# How to modify global stiffness matrix before solving it by SMTNewtonIteration[]?

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I'm trying to use the Model Order Reduction technique to reduce the stiffness matrix in AceFEM/AceGen. But there is a problem with the manipulation of the global stiffness before solving it by SMTNewtonIteration[]. Has anyone met some problem like this?

Comment: "there is a problem" - what problem? Can you include enough code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: hello MarcoB, 
because using SMTNewtonIteration[] will automatically assemble the stiffness matrix and solve it. But I want to modify or manipulate the global stiffness matrix before solving it. Is it possible to do that in AceFEM/AceGen?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementProgramming.html#1004024637)?

Comment: I don't think that what you are looking for is possible. [link1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160433/acefem-manipulation-of-smtdatamatrixglobal-after-building-but-before-solvin) and [link2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253287/acefem-globaltask?rq=1)

Comment: The direct answer is No, due to reasons you mentioned. However there are some ways one could circumvent this issue, but It depends what you want to do. You can introduce 2 domains and make 2 element codes. Then deactivate domain 2, assemble the FULL tangent of domain1, and then do some operations on it and export it to elementData to elements 2, activate them and deactivate elements 1 and you can deactivate required nodes if needed. Then the SMTNewtonIteration will assemble Tangent of elements 2. Or you can contact author, prof. Korelc and ask him for the c source code.

Comment: @Blaz, thanks a lot for your kind reply. I will try your suggestion. :)

Comment: Because the matrices in AceFEM are stored in compressed format, the change of size or sparsity structure requires construction of a new matrix. You can use SMTData["TangentMatrix"] to transfer the tangent matrix to Mathematica where you can do any kind of modifications (POD...). With the results, you can then formulate reduced problem as a new AceFEM session.

Comment: @Jozek thank you so much for your useful explanation. "formulate reduced problem as a new AceFEM session". Does this mean that I have to reload AceFEM again? or is there another meaning for this?